# Switch to a certain commit in missing branch in GIT

Tags: git, console, branch, bitbucket, sourcetree

The code I have been writing for 5 days disappered after tapping wrong button. I have been working in HEAD. And made 3 commits in 5 days. In BitBucket desktop app I have twice tapped a different branch and now its gone. I can't find commits that were not sent to the server.

The branch doesn't come up, but commits are visible in history:

```
Macintosh:repo admin$ git branch -a
* HEAD
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

Macintosh:repo admin$ git branch
* HEAD
  master
```

Here is the history of commits:

```
Macintosh:repo admin$ git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate  $(git reflog | awk '{print $1}')
warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
* 1d2bc57 THIRD
* d2a0291 SECOND
* 40c2d66 FIRST
| * 7100271 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, HEAD) CURRENT
|/  
* bc35e2f OLDCOMMINT
```

The Desktop app shows empty HEAD branch, thats why I can't understand what is going on here.
How do I switch from "7100271" (CURRENT) to "1d2bc57" (THIRD) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm glad that you found a solution below, but it's worth pointing out that a "Bitbucket desktop app" doesn't currently exist. Perhaps you mean [SourceTree](https://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree)?

Comment: Yes, certainly. Isn't it the official app?

Comment: Both products come from the same company, but I wouldn't call SourceTree official. Many people use Bitbucket with other clients, and many people use SourceTree with other repository hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the data by simply using git checkout on the commit sha

```
git checkout 1d2bc57
```

After this you may not be on any branch (a 'detached head state') anymore, in which case you can just create a new branch.

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for fast response. How can I then make my current branch the main one. So obviously, make GIT think that master is "THIRD", rather than "CURRENT"?

Comment: And when I try to create a new branch I receive following errors: warning: refname 'HEAD' is ambiguous.
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'HEAD'.

Comment: I think the error might be caused by you having another branch named 'HEAD'. Try renaming it to something else using `git branch -m HEAD newBranch` . You then should be able to use `git rebase master` while in the new branch to transfer all of the changes into master.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git reflog` to obtain a history of all commits you checked out or committed.

Once you find your most recent commit, use `git checkout <hash>` to check out that commit.

Comment: Is the short hash enough for that or only the full one?

Comment: Fixed that, thanks for participation and short response!

Answer (score 1):

What has happened here is that you have created a branch (regular, ordinary, local branch) named `HEAD`, whose name conflicts with the special name `HEAD` that Git uses to know which branch you're on.

When you check out a branch like `master`, Git writes the branch name into the `HEAD` file.  If you check out the branch named `HEAD`, Git will write `HEAD` into the `HEAD` file.  This entire situation is highly confusing: it's like going to a party, or a classroom, and finding out that everyone is named Ashot. :-)

The best thing to do here is to rename or remove the *branch* that is named `HEAD` (rename or kill off the extra Ashot, as it were).  To rename it from the command line:

```
$ git branch -m HEAD new-name
```

I have no idea how to do this from some fancy GUI (there may not be any way to fix it from there, GUIs tend to be limited).

Comment: Is there a way to make GIT write temporary commits in something named not HEAD?

Comment: No: you can get onto *no* branch (using `git checkout --detach` or `git checkout <sha-1>`), after which `HEAD` contains the raw SHA-1 of the current commit, rather than the name of the branch from which to get that commit ID. But either way, the underlying name here is `HEAD`: it's just a question of whether `.git/HEAD` contains the *raw ID* of a commit, or the *name of a branch* that gives you the ID of the commit. (You can use a named branch for a while, then switch away from it and *delete* the name, at which point all the commits are forgotten and are up for garbage-collection.)